# Setting all cookies to variables?

Tags: php

I'm trying to set all active cookies to variables in which the names would correspond to the name of the cookie, which I tried to accomplish using a variable variable. http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

```
function setcookie_vars() {
    if(isset($_SERVER["HTTP_COOKIE"])) {
        $cookies = explode(";", $_SERVER["HTTP_COOKIE"]);
        foreach($cookies as $cookie) {
            $parts = explode("=", $cookie);
            $name = trim($parts[0]);
            $value = trim($parts[1]);
            $$name = $value;
            return $$name;
        }
    }
}
print_r(${$test}); // should output the value for $_COOKIE["test"];
```

For instance, if the cookie's name was "test," the variable's name would be $test with the same value set in the cookie for that name. I tried to test this out with cookies set beforehand and I got (and I checked that the cookie was already set):

```
    Notice: Undefined variable: test in...
    Notice: Undefined variable: in...
```

I was unable to find any problem similar to this on the web, probably because it's fairly customized.

Comment: This is generally a very bad idea and can cause major security flaws, strange bugs, and more. `register_globals` was removed from PHP for a reason.

Comment: @minitech Will the method Ben Rowe suggested be a bad idea as well? Is it because the cookie value can be anything?

Comment: It's not quite as bad, as the code given will prefix each variable with `cookie_`. But no, that's not the security problem. Take a look at [the example misuse here](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php).

Comment: I see, so it has to do with scoping. I won't be using this script for anything that has to do with security, so I'll be fine. Thanks for the warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace your entire function with:

```
extract($_COOKIE, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, 'cookie');

echo $cookie_nameOfCookie;
```

Comment: Thanks, I will test this out now. I cannot believe all these frustrating hours trying to get my function to work could be solved this easily.

Comment: It worked, but the first parameter should be $_COOKIE :) Thank you!